# Creating a python virtualenv in Ubuntu 12.04 accessing system installed python packages before local venv packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

I am installing virtualenv and it seems to access the system site packages before accessing the local site packages. Ipython is required by some other programs so it was automatically installed. This only happened recently and now it finds that version instead of the one found locally in the environment.

How do I tell the environment to use local packages within the environment before global packages? Can you set the Path variable for within the environment?

Ended up being an error with previously had set the PYTHON_PATH variable in .bashrc so this was looking in the system built directories before looking locally. Kind of defeating the purpose of virtual_env.

Comment: have you activated the virtualenv with `source /path_to_virtualenv/bin/activate`?

Comment: Use the --no-site-packages option while installing

Comment: Do you mean this problem happens inside Ipython shell? If so, install and use Ipython inside the virtualenv.

Comment: @Vivek - yes I read about that but is there anyway to do it after the fact?? I already have all the packages setup in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using distribute + pip to manage dependencies simply run `pip -l freeze > requirements.txt`, this creates a dependency list of all your local packages. Next remove the current virtualenv; rerun the `virtualenv` command and specify the `--no-site-packages` option. Activate your new environment and finally `pip install -r requirements.txt` to download all the dependencies from the requirements file.

Comment: If you do this, you need to make sure you have all the build requirements installed for python, and any other packages that you might have installed from your package manager. For example, if you have `psycopg` installed, you need to `apt-get build-dep psycopg` first_ before attempting to install it in your virtualenv otherwise your install will fail.